# Unable to grant secure file permissions to a pipeline via REST API

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline that publishes a secure file to the pipeline library. What I would like to do is immediately grant that file permissions to a pipeline (so that I don't have to go in and manually do so). I have been following this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/pipeline-permissions/update-pipeline-permisions-for-resources

My PATCH method is as follows:

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://dev.azure.com/{myOrganization}/{myProject}/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions?api-version=7.0-preview.1' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic {myAuth}  ' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '[
  {
    "resource": {
      "type": "secureFile",
      "id": "{mySecureFileId}"
    },
    "pipelines": [
      {
        "id": {myPipelineId},
        "authorized": true
      }
    ]
  }
]'
```

For reference, the URL to the secure file is:

[https://dev.azure.com/{myOrganization}/{myProject}/_library?itemType=SecureFiles&view=SecureFileView&secureFileId={mySecureFileId}&path={secureFileName}](https://dev.azure.com/%7BmyOrganization%7D/%7BmyProject%7D/_library?itemType=SecureFiles&view=SecureFileView&secureFileId=%7BmySecureFileId%7D&path=%7BsecureFileName%7D)

and the URL to my pipeline is:

[https://dev.azure.com/{myOrganization}/{myProject}/_build?definitionId={myPipelineId}&_a=summary](https://dev.azure.com/%7BmyOrganization%7D/%7BmyProject%7D/_build?definitionId=%7BmyPipelineId%7D&_a=summary)

But my response is always:

```
Status: 200 OK

{
    "count": 0,
    "value": []
}
```

No permissions get set. The documentation does say that a 200 response is correct, but the count being 0 means that nothing was patched. I confirmed that the resource type of **secureFile** is correct when I change the **secureFileId** or **pipelineId** to ones that do not exist, I get an expected 404 response.

So as far as I can tell, my syntax and IDs are all correct, but I still have not been able to successfully grant the permissions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using: [Pipeline Permissions - Update Pipeline Permisions For Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/pipeline-permissions/update-pipeline-permisions-for-resources?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP), in your scenario, you should use: [Pipeline Permissions - Update Pipeline Permisions For Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/pipeline-permissions/update-pipeline-permisions-for-resource?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

[Pipeline Permissions - Update Pipeline Permisions For Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/pipeline-permissions/update-pipeline-permisions-for-resource?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) is used to Authorizes/Unauthorizes a list of definitions for a given resource.

So modify your API as below, it should work:

PATCH [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions/{resourceType}/{resourceId}?api-version=7.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions/%7BresourceType%7D/%7BresourceId%7D?api-version=7.0-preview.1)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Modify your script as below:

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions/{resourceType}/{resourceId}?api-version=7.0-preview.1' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic {myAuth}  ' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '[
  {
    "pipelines": [
      {
        "id": {myPipelineId},
        "authorized": true
      }
    ]
  }
]'
```

Comment: This was absolutely the answer! Such a small difference between the two endpoints; I never would have figured this out on my own. Thank you very much for the detailed pictures and walkthrough!